# Can't retrieve product (post) ID using Shopp e-commerce plugin

Tags: plugin-shopp

I'm using the shopp e-commerce plugin. In my template file I need to get the id of the product (post). The online docs for shopp list `shopp('product', 'id')` but irritatingly this prints the id and there appears to be no alternative that simply returns it. Also confusing, when I do `$post->ID` it returns -42... which is weird.

Can anyone help me return the post id of individual products inside the shopp loop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's turns out that you can add `return=true` to any of the theme template tags:

```
shopp('product', 'id', 'return=true');
```

As of writing this, that is not mentioned in the documentation at all. Shopp support was also able to confirm that the $post->ID variable does get over-written in a number of situations, so the strange value I was seeing is not surprising.

Comment: a shorthand for this command would be `shopp('product.get-id');` this works for every shopp() tag.

Answer (score -1):

This also works to get the current product's id:

```
$product_id = ShoppProduct()->id;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
$product_id = shopp('product','id','return=true');
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to say with the answer. Please edit the Answer again and add some details with the code so that someone understand easily.